# Camel log doesn't work

Tags: spring, logging, apache-camel, spring-camel

Camel route:

```
  from("seda:rest_upload")
                .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "Got new file from sftp with name ${header.filename}")
                .to("file://rest_files?fileName=${header.filename}");
```

I see new files into `rest_files` but I don't see log about it.

**What do I wrong?**

### P.S.

Bu the way I tried to write:

```
  from("seda:rest_upload")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    logger.info("Got new file from sftp with name {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader("filename"));
                }
            })
            .to("file://rest_files?fileName=${header.filename}");
```

The behaviour really strange - file saves successfully but process method is not invoked.

Comment: Routes looks okay. 
May be your logging is set to different level and you are logging as WARN. Double check this.

Comment: @pvpkiran I recheck it. I wrote logger.info near and it works correct

Comment: @pvpkiran, do you know why process method is not invoked?

Comment: How are you checking if process didn't work? through log statement ? if so then try to put a smiple log.info statement without any variable and check

Comment: @pvpkiran I put debug point  on this line

Comment: Sounds like you have not configured your logging correctly. Surely the Camel logger works as it just uses slf4j-api under the hood. So find out how to configure slf4j logging with how you run the Java JVM.